# How does passing Boolean as an argument work?

Tags: javascript

Okay, the problem was, given an array, remove all elements that are 'falsey'.

This was my solution to said problem (which works):

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  var trueArr = [];
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i]){
            trueArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
  return(trueArr);
}

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

This works, and passes the tests. But here's the solution that was given:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
```

I've read the MDN article on Boolean AND filter and still don't get how this works? What exactly is happening here? Is Boolean the callback function? If so, how does that work, in the back end? I'm just sitting here scratching my head.

Comment: `Boolean` is a constructor which creates a boolean, so its a function that returns true for truthy values and false for falsey ones, so by filtering on it you remove all falsey values

Comment: It is comparing each and every element of arr(array) with passed Boolean value and return array of elements that matches with passed value. You can use filter with non Boolean value too.

Comment: `[7, "ate", "", false, 9].filter(i => { return Boolean(i) })`

Comment: @NickA how though? I thought Boolean just checks if a value is truthy or falsey? So how is it returning JUST the truthy values? It doesn't actually say filter out the non-truthy values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) object is an object wrapper for a boolean value. When calling `Boolean` you are actually calling a function (See snippet) with a parameter - Exactly what you need in the callback for `Array.filter()`.

`new Boolean([value])` is called

Depending on the parameter, the returned value will be `true` or `false` (See snippet).

```js
console.log(Boolean); //Constructor
console.log(Boolean(0)); //Falsy value
console.log(Boolean("foo")); //Truthy value
```

Comment: Okay, I get this - but where is it getting the parameter from? 

For instance, when calling filter, with a regular callback, it would be something like this: 

`arr.filter(function(x){});` where "X" is the placeholder for the array item being tested, yes? But when using Boolean as the callback, how does it know which array item is being tested? Sorry if this question makes no sense, I just can't seem to figure out how it's working in the back. In my head, it should be written like this:

`arr.filter(function(Boolean(x){});` where x is the item of the array being tested. No?

Comment: `arr.filter(Boolean)` is the same as `arr.filter(x=>Boolean(x))`. The `x` comes from `filter` callback

Answer (score 3):

From [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> callback
>   Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise

From [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

> The value passed as the first parameter is converted to a boolean value

So yes. It is the callback. It is a function (built into the JS language) that returns true or false, which is what the filter function expects the function passed to it to do.

Comment: Thanks! This cleared it up, mostly! I just couldn't figure out how it was returning just the truthy values. 

One more question though: in this case, how is it cycling through the elements in the array? In a normal scenario, I would type out:

`arr.filter(function(x){})`

Where 'x' is a placeholder for the array item yes? In that case, shouldn't I need to mention that when calling Boolean as a callback? Like this: 

`arr.filter(function(Boolean(x){});`

Comment: @firefiber — "how is it cycling through the elements in the array?" —
 Because that is what `filter` does. " would type out" — Boolean is a function that accepts an argument. Why would you need to wrap it in another function?

Answer (score 0):

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
```

The code above is equivalent to:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(arr) {
    return Boolean(arr);
  });
}
```

Also, [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) returns `false` when passed a falsey parameter. As a result those are filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.filter(Boolean);
```

is the same than

```
arr.filter(function (x) { return Boolean(x); });
```

> Since Boolean constructor is also a function, it returns either true
>   for ‘truthy’ argument or false for ‘falsy’ argument.

http://www.devign.me/javascript-tip-remove-falsy-items-out-of-an-array